# How to Detect Mousedown + Mousemove Left or Right Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can detect whether the mousemove is toward Left or Right?

```js
 $('.container').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).mousemove(function(){
      //if Moves Left { console.log("Moving Left"); }
      //if Moves Right {  console.log("Moving Right"); }
    });
});     
  $('.container').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

```css
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Definitely one off the many solution:

```
$('.container').mousedown(function(e1){
    var mx = e1.pageX;//register the mouse down position

    $(this).mousemove(function(e2){

        if (e2.pageX > mx){ //right w.r.t mouse down position
            console.log("Moved Right");
        } else {
            console.log("Moved Left")
        }
    });
});     
  $('.container').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/2xxwwvj3/)

Comment: This sees if the mouse is left or right of the starting (mouse down) position. You have to update mx in the mouse move if you want to know if it's moving left / right.

Comment: yea that was there in my mind when i answered but the question did not point whether it has to be relative to the current position or relative to the point when he puts the mouse down...

Answer (score 2):

Hay this is quite easy just add this code inside you script tag and view on your console.

```js
var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
bodyElement.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouseDirection, false);
 
var xDirection = "";
var yDirection = "";
 
var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 0;
 
function getMouseDirection(e) {
    //deal with the horizontal case
    if (oldX < e.pageX) {
        xDirection = "right";
    } else {
        xDirection = "left";
    }
 
    //deal with the vertical case
    if (oldY < e.pageY) {
        yDirection = "down";
    } else {
        yDirection = "up";
    }
 
    oldX = e.pageX;
    oldY = e.pageY;
 
    console.log(xDirection + " " + yDirection);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $('.container').mousedown(function(e){
    var prevX = e.clientX;
    $(this).mousemove(function(e){
      
      if(e.clientX < prevX) { console.log("Moving Left"); }
      if(e.clientX > prevX) {  console.log("Moving Right"); }
      prevX = e.clientX;
    });
});     
  $('.container').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

```css
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```